# find and move files without overwriting and with output

Tags: linux, files, find, mv

I'm trying to find and move some files from */home/user/fol1* to */home/user/fol2*.
Generally I would use

```
find . -type f -name "abc*" -exec mv -t "/path/to/foo/bar" {} +
```

but this overwrites files with same names already present in */path/to/foo/bar*.
I want it to skip the files if already present there.
If this requires a loop, I also need an output either plain output on shell or in a log file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to have all files in a single directory `/path/to/foo/bar` even if they were in subdirectories? Example: File `baz/abcdef` would be moved to `/path/to/foo/bar/abcdef`. Or would you want `/path/to/foo/bar/baz/abcdef`? In case you don't have files in subdirectories you would not need `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `n` option:

```
find . -type f -name "abc*" -exec mv -nt "/path/to/foo/bar" "{}" +
```

From `man mv`:

```
-n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file
```

Comment: NB: this solution does not preserve directory structure. It will put `source/some/dir/file.ext` into `dest/file.ext`. A lot of fun will happen if the source recursively contains multiple files named `file.ext`.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Mac Terminal, and this command Is giving good result:

find FIle_Origin -type f -name "File_Name" -exec mv {} File_destination/ ;

Comment: This answer is identical to [your answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592943/116858). In this case I have not corrected its syntax as it doesn't at all try to address the issue in the actual question.  In fact, as I pointed out in a comment to your other answer, it suffers from the same issue that the user in this question has.